# plugins on PhoneGap 3.5 don't work

Tags: cordova, touch, phonegap-plugins

I am a newbie in Mobile app development. 
I work with sencha touch with PhoneGap. I recently upgraded to PhoneGap 3.5. Post which the plugins like camera , device and others don't work. I build the app by this command "sencha app build -run native". Has anything changed in PhoneGap 3.5?

Comment: I was on phone gap 3.2 earlier.

Comment: please show what you have done here

Comment: I followed this.. http://www.sencha.com/blog/leveraging-phonegap-within-sencha-touch/

Answer (score 0):

If you're upgrading from < 3.0, you will need to start referencing each plugin you use (camera, device, geolocation, ...) individually on your config files, whether you are using build.phonegap.com or compiling on your machine. [Here's some more info](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs).

Comment: Thanks. I have this on my config file: <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>   Do you mean something else?